# gnome disk utility freezes when try to format external disk?

Tags: debian, hard-disk

when i try to format an external disk with the gnome disk utility the application freezes after 5-10 seconds and than my debian have to reboot or the application just closes by itself without doing anything when i have a terminal open and run top the process sometimes goes up to 100% or quit alone how can i check why this happens? i try to update with apt-get but still got the same problem what can i do now i run a debian with gnome desktop